# How to find files matching a regex and save each result in an array?

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, shell, find

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(find . -type f -name -regex '\w{8}[-]\w{4}[-]\w{4}[-]\w{4}[-]\w{12}')
echo $result
```

I tried the above but used a variable and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: So, you want to match, say, `12345678-1234-1234-123456789012`? Or something like `12345678-1234-1234-123456789012.txt` or `12345678-1234-1234-123456789012-blah.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapfile -td '' myarray \
< <(find . -type f -regextype egrep \
    -regex '.*/\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}' -print0)

# iterate the array in a loop
for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Assuming you were looking for files matching this regex.

Answer (score 1):

I bet `find` uses basic regular expressions by default, so `\w` is probably not known, and the braces would have to be escaped. Add a `-regextype` option (and remove -name):

```sh
re='.*[[:alnum:]]{8}-[[:alnum:]]{4}-[[:alnum:]]{4}-[[:alnum:]]{4}-[[:alnum:]]{12}.*'
find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex "$re"
```

Note that my `find` man page says about `-regex`:

> This is a match on the whole path, not a search.

Which means the leading *and* trailing `.*` are necessary to ensure the pattern matches the whole path.

And to capture the results into an array (assuming no newlines in the filenames), use the bash `mapfile` command, redirecting from a process substitution.

```sh
mapfile -t files < <(find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex "$re")
```

Comment: Thanks man ,,But I get this error find: paths must precede expression: `egrep'

Comment: Thanks man how do make the reg strictly follow the rule like it must follow the pattern

Comment: find is pretty finicky about where to put options, I haven't put the time in to really get expert. Try this order: `-regextype -type -regex`

Comment: I don't understand your 2nd comment.

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out thanks man you rock!